# show default image when 404

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with html5 markup, jquery and css3 and displaying an image to the user of a product.

If the product image does not show I need a default image to show.

Was thinking if I set a css class on image tag to show the default image but let the src on the image tag have the real product image. If thats not found, the classes default image shows.

Is this possible with css and if so, how?

Comment: One option would be to set the background image to a default image.

Comment: any tips of how to do this with css?

Comment: css doesn't really know about requests so its not very likely possible.